# Need help to fix my .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My index.php file is located at:

> myserverHost/api/public/

which include api calls like getting token. like:

> myserverHost/api/public/token

It works only if i type exact URL. i.e.

> myserverHost/api/public/token

i am trying to write rewrite rule where i can use:

> myserverHost/api/token

here what i have tried in my .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /api/

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

# Make sure $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated warning does not appear
#php_value   always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
```

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see any attempt to code what you ask in that configuration file you posted.

Comment: Dear, i am new to this topic. i have mentioned my code attempt

Comment: Shouldn't you just change the deployment so the `DocumentRoot` is `public`? or do you want the `public` displayed in some instances?

Comment: i don't want public to be displayed in my url. instead of myserverHost/api/public/token i want to use myserverHost/api/token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will remove public in format public/x -> X

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /api/

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I am getting ```Not Found

The requested URL /api/token was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.```

Comment: my .htaccess file is located at /api/public directory